# SQLite LEFT JOIN & WHERE Clause confusion

Tags: sqlite, left-join, where-clause

I have two Tables:

**Table 1: Questions**:

```
QuestionId NUMERIC
Title      TEXT
```

**Test Data in Question Table:**

```
QuestionId     Title
1              What is your name?
2              What is your age?
```

**Table 2: Answers:**

```
AnswerId     NUMERIC
PersonId     NUMERIC
QuestionId   NUMERIC
Answer       TEXT
```

If there is **NO DATA in Answers Table** then below **query returns correct results (2 rows)**:

```
SELECT  q.QuestionId, q.Title, a.Answer
FROM    Questions q
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Answers a ON q.QuestionId = a.QuestionId
WHERE    a.PersonId = 2 OR a.PersonId IS null
```

**But if i have for example 1 record in Answer Table like**:

```
AnswerId     1
PersonId     1
QuestionId   1
Answer       'My Name is Yaqub'
```

Below query works fine:

```
SELECT  q.QuestionId, q.Title, a.Answer
FROM    Questions q
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Answers a ON q.QuestionId = a.QuestionId
WHERE    a.PersonId = 1 OR a.PersonId IS null
```

**But this query returns just one row**:

```
SELECT  q.QuestionId, q.Title, a.Answer
FROM    Questions q
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Answers a ON q.QuestionId = a.QuestionId
WHERE    a.PersonId = 2 OR a.PersonId IS null
```

The above query returns just one row which is wrong, becuase i have two questions in Question Table & the above query should return both of them because of the condition 'OR a.PersonId IS null'.

**Why its not returning TWO Rows?**

**Desired Results:**

I want to get all the questions(2 rows) & those answers where PersonId has some value,for example TWO rows for Person 2 because i have no data for him in the Answer Table.

Comment: Reason for DOWN VOTE please?

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but your question is not very clear.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**I FOUND the SOLUTION:**

```
SELECT q.QuestionId, q.Title, a.Answer
FROM Questions q
 LEFT OUTER JOIN Answers a ON q.QuestionId = a.QuestionId AND 
(a.PersonId = 2 OR a.PersonId IS null)
```

This query will list all the questions & the WHERE clause will filter out those answers where PersonID has a specific value or is null. So whenever there's an answer to a question, i'll get no NULL values for PersonID.

Comment: FYI, that's a correlated subquery, and correlated subqueries are well-known to suck, performance-wise.  Why don't you do the sane thing and remove your `where` clause?

Comment: Sorry for late reply, i was bussy!!
I can not exclude the where Clause becuase i need to show the questions per person & the answers if they exist for that person.

Comment: The WHERE clause will filter out those answers where PersonID has a specific value or is null. So whenever there's an answer to a question, i'll get no NULL values for PersonID

Comment: great!  my version of SQLite does not accept OUTER, but aside from that, you solved my issue.  UPVOTED

Answer (score 6):

You can do it just like this:

```
SELECT q.QuestionId, q.Title, a.Answer
FROM Questions q
 LEFT OUTER JOIN Answers a ON q.QuestionId = a.QuestionId AND 
a.PersonId = 2
```

The query still returns records with PersonId = null because of outer join.

Answer (score 1):

This is what you have when you do the join, before the `where` is applied:

```
QuestionID    AnswerID    PersonID
1             1           1
2             null        null
```

There actually is only one record in the questions table that matches `(PersonID = 2 or PersonID is null)`, so you should expect only one row.

Did you mean to put

```
a.PersonId = 1 OR a.PersonId IS null
```

instead?

Comment: Yes, thats what i require... I need to get data from the questions table based on PersonId.

Comment: @YaqubAhmad - What Blorgbeard is trying to say is that your `where` clause filters out the second row.  If you don't specify `where PersonId is null`, then the query returns two rows.

Comment: Actually i need to get the questions for different persons, so my WHERE Clause can be a.PersonId = 1, a.PersonId = 1 & so on. Please check my question again.

Comment: @JackManey: I have a.PersonId IS null, so it should return both the rows.

Comment: Again, you're filtering out the second row by requiring `PersonID` to be null.  If you want two rows, then don't make that restriction.  It's that simple.

Comment: @JackManey: Jack i am sorry i can't understand the role of a.PersonId IS null

Comment: @YaqubAhmad what is the result you want, just in english, not SQL?

Comment: @YaqubAhmad - You're filtering out rows where `a.PersonId` is not null.  Don't do that.

Comment: I want to get two rows (Questions) for Person 2 because i have no data for him in the Answer Table.

Comment: Ummmm...you only have one person.

Answer (score 0):

@Yaqub. If you want to show all the question from then i think you need to apply the RIGHT OUTER JOIN to replace the Left Outer Join so it will take all the questions. thanks

Comment: No, that will show all the answers (answers is on the right side of the join). To show all the questions he just needs to remove his where clause.

Comment: @YaqubAhmad - Then change the order of the tables in which you're joining.  Sheesh!